# Conditional definition of multicolumn format

Tags: tables, macros, multicolumn

I'm making a table (similar to a calendar) in which I have a date or some short string in the upper right of each table cell, and then have the contents of that cell left aligned.

I am trying to write a little `\newcommand` to help make this simpler to do.

Here's the long way to do my table, but it comes out correct:

```
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|r|}{\textbf{1}} & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{\textbf{2}} & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{\textbf{3}} \\
first thing & second thing & third thing \\
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|r|}{\textbf{4}} & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{\textbf{New 1}} & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{\textbf{2}} \\
fourth thing & restarting &  \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
```

I was trying to be clever and not repeat myself so was trying to do two things:

1. Set up a counter to do the counting in each cell
2. Write a `\newcommand` so that I don't have to keep repeating that `\multicolumn` code in each cell.

I haven't been able to get it to work, and I get lots of "Illegal pream-token" or "Misplaced \omit" errors in compiling.

Here's what I tried:

In the document header:

```
\newcounter{DateNumber}
\setcounter{DateNumber}{22}
\newcommand{\datehead}[2]{%
    \multicolumn{1}{%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{first}}{|r|}{r|}}%
        {\textbf{#1 \theDateNumber}}\stepcounter{DateNumber}%
}
```

The table:

```
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
\hline
\datehead{}{first} & \datehead{}{} & \datehead{}{} \\
first thing & second thing & third thing \\
\hline
\datehead{}{first} & \setcounter{DateNumber}{1}\datehead{New} & \datehead{}\\
fourth thing & restarting &  \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `\multicolumn` for this, but just `\hspace*{\fill}`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{head}
\newcommand{\head}[1]{\stepcounter{head}\hspace*{\fill}\bfseries #1 \thehead}
\newcommand{\headnew}[1]{\setcounter{head}{0}\head{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
\hline
\head{} & \head{} & \head{} \\
first thing & second thing & third thing \\
\hline
\head{} & \headnew{New} & \head{} \\
fourth thing & restarting &  \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]